# Python: weekday position of following months

Tags: python, date, weekday

Given a date, how do you know the weekday position in the month (ex: third tuesday of the month) and how do you get the date for the same weekday for the next month (ex: third tuesday of the month+1)?

Comment: You've already asked two other questions about relative dates and have received plenty of helpful information; you should be able to figure this out from those answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the examples below, `d` is a `datetime.date` object.

To get the "index" of the day within the current month, use

```
def weekday_index(d):
    return (d.day + 6) // 7
```

This formula will work independent of what weekday the date actually is.  To get the day wich is the same weekday with the same weekday index within the next month, the simplest way seems to be

```
d_next = d + datetime.timedelta(weeks=4)
if weekday_index(d_next) < weekday_index(d):
    d_next += datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)
```

This uses the fact the the date you are looking for is either 4 weeks or 5 weeks after `d`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module. Specifically the [weekday](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday) method of the [date](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#date-objects)
object. [isocalendar](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar) might be helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
cnt=1
d=datetime.datetime.now()
d1=datetime.datetime(d.year,d.month,1,d.hour,d.minute,d.second,d.microsecond)
while(d1.day!=d.day):
  if 6-d1.weekday()==1:cnt=cnt+1
  d1=d1+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print cnt #print current date week position
```